read csv file from url using httpclient
I am trying to read csv using HttpClient
    [Test, Explicit]
    public async Task ImportSymbolsTestAsync()
    {
        var url = "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/equities/EQUITY_L.csv";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

But getting error

Message:  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred
while sending the request.   ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to
read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was
forcibly closed by the remote host..   ---->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : An existing connection was
forcibly closed by the remote host.
Stack Trace:  HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken
cancellationToken) RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

If I try the same thing with postman, then it works. What could be the issue?

You may try the same thing, but I am pretty confident that it's not the same request on the wire. Fire up a sniffer and diff requests from PostMan and your App. There must be some Header maybe missing or wrong so the remote host rejects your request.

Examine the http headers sent by postman, and try to debug and see the http headers of the request to see if there are any differences. Other possibility could be an unsupported tls version from nsearchives.nseindia.com. In code you indicate tle 1.3 or 1.2, not sure what postman does on its side.

Make sure you're using HttpClient properly:
private static readonly HttpClient _Client = new HttpClient();

static MyTestClass()
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}

[Test, Explicit]
public async Task ImportSymbolsTestAsync()
{
    var url = "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/equities/EQUITY_L.csv";
    using (var response = await _Client.GetAsync(url))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}


based on these articles, I can improve performance. but it does not address my current problem...
